# How to array of int transform into 2d array of binary value of every array number?

Tags: c++

Hi i'm trying to find binary value of every element of array and to set it in 2d array. 
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

void tobin(int a,int b[]);

int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int b[8];//bin array
    int d[3][8]; //2d array
    int c[3] = {6,15,24}; //int array

    //My code for transformation from array to 2d array
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            tobin(c[i],b);
            for(j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                d[i][j]=b[j];

            }
        }

    //Printing of 2d array
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<8;j++)
                std::cout<<d[i][j];
            std::cout<<std::endl;
        }
}

//Function for convert int to bin
void tobin(int a,int b[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        b[i]=a%2;
        a/=2;
    }
}
```

And here my output:

```
01100000
11110000
00011000
00-16437331793270200193648149632765
014196397000-640061051-1985511146
419616001936481488327650000
16416403251985832910-46743922719940467470000
004196848019364814963276510
```

First 3 lines is what i was looking for, but i don't know what is the rest.
Can someone help me to fix this. And to give me explanation why is this happening or link to explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last for-loop (the one that prints) should only have `i<3` as its condition.  Right now `i` is allowed to go to 7, but then `d[i][j]` is out of bounds and prints garbage.

Comment: happens to me all the time  :)  keep yer eyes peeled matey!